# Is there a package that provides /sbin/consoletype?

Tags: server

Is there a ubuntu package that provides /sbin/consoletype?
https://linux.die.net/man/1/consoletype

Thank you

Comment: You can answer this for yourself using the search feature of http://packages.ubuntu.com

Comment: I tried that and no results, any help is appreciated.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=consoletype&searchon=names

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details; some CLI tools can look further than the aforementioned URL, but CLI command varies on release (Ubuntu Core Server will use different commands to Ubuntu Server, but you've not provided specific details on product/release).   Do note *consoletype* is *deprecated* so may not exist if your release is recent.

Comment: Oh sorry i just updated the question to add the OS version, I figured consoletype is a very generic

Comment: `/etc/sysconfig/` is not used in Ubuntu - that's more on the RHEL side of the family. So I wouldn't expect it to be available or even work in Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 has passed its End-Of-Life date, and is no longer supported on AskUbuntu.

Comment: Ahh duly noted I am doing some Extended Security Maintenance on a server before a planned upgrade. I figured its supported till 2026 https://ubuntu.com/16-04

Comment: Extended Security Maintenance is exactly what it says on the tin: Security patches. But nothing else -- no bugfixes, no community support.

Comment: Duly noted no community support for Extended Security Maintenance

Answer (score 1):

Consoletype appears to be a system V init program and is not provided on Ubuntu, consoletype from Gentoo appears to work:
https://gitweb.gentoo.org/proj/gentoo-functions.git/tree/consoletype.c

To compile

```
gcc -o consoletype consoletype.c
```

I put it in /opt and it works YMMV